# Stretching image in a pdf using writeHTMLCell()

Tags: php, pdf, fpdi

I am using FPDI library to convert from html to pdf. I need to stretch images to bigger then original size and it seems to me they will not go a pixel bigger. I can stretch them down but not up.

I am using the function writeHTMLCell and passing it a simple:

```
<img src="image.jpg" width='500' height='500' />
```

I guess my question is: is this a known limitation of the library? PDF? Or am I missing something obvious. This is a project I am asked to debug and first time with this library.

Thanks to all.

Comment: From my experience using it once before, I remember it being a limitation of the library.

Comment: @Baez aaaaaw. :( Well I found a image() method in the class I'll see if it would let me resize UP.

Comment: Great, let me know if you find it works. I'm sure I'll be requested to use it again later too!

Comment: Nothing worked it seems.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is an older question. Couldn't you resize the image using ImageMagick and then use the new resized image inside the Image() function?

Comment: @SSHThis sure but back then I was still wondering if it could be done from the library. Also depending on the amount of images and reports (it was reports) generated it could make the script pretty slow. Nice idea tho thanks for sharing!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick response, I'm in a similar dilemma this morning